# Need help to inserting 100 records in loop, continue where it stop from and break once the records are completed.

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help to inserting 100 records in loop, continue where it stop from and break once the records are completed.

```
Alter PROCEDURE ETL.ETLPurge @PurgeYear INT
AS
BEGIN

  DECLARE @BatchId INT = (SELECT BatchId FROM Tracker)
  declare @Count int
  declare @batchsize int  
  set @batchsize =  100  

  --set @Count = @@rowcount 

 SELECT DISTINCT IDENTITY(INT,1,1) AS ID, MC.ID
  INTO #tmp
  FROM Contact MC
  JOIN Extract CE
    ON MC.ExtractID = CE.ExtractID
  LEFT JOIN Application A 
    ON MC.ID = A.ID
WHERE CE.Year < @PurgeYear   
 AND A.ApplicationId IS NULL  

--declare @counter bigint
--set @counter = 1
--while @counter < 500 
--Begin

--while 1 = 1 
--begin 
Create  NONCLUSTERED INDEX nix_ID
on #tmp(ID) 

--while 1=1
--begin 
INSERT  
--Top (@batchsize) 
INTO Table1 (Values ………)

(
SELECT top (@batchsize)  
@BatchID,  
Values ……..) 
  FROM Contact MC
 inner join 
       #tmp TK on MC.ContactID = TK.ContactID

    --where TK.ID between @batchsize and @ctr + 1
     )
 if @@ROWCOUNT < @batchsize 
 break 
 end 
 --  --continue  
 --  --if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
 -- Break 
end 
 --end 
--number of rows inserted should equal number of rows deleted.
```

Comment: What's the actual question here? Does this code not do what you need it to do? If not, in what way? Details, details, details...

Comment: Why don't you forget about the batches and just insert all the records?

Comment: Hi Aaron , thanks for the reply , actually this code works fine , but i have to process this in a while loop or maybe using a cursor  by updating 100 records at a time , i have more then 100 records in the table , all i need it that it should process 100 records for each interval , than continue where it stops from and once it reaches the final end update , break the loop

Comment: Hi Dan , we have 80 million records and there are chances of timeout & failure for this , hence i am testing this with batches

Comment: ?  This seems like having to travel 8 miles and stopping every 10 feet to rebuild your car from scratch.   80 million records isn't too heavy, but batching them in 100's will turn this from an hour long process to a 3 week process.  SQL is a set based language, loops to this iteration is not good.

Comment: Hi Twelfth, it's a test that i am performing for 100 records on my local. i will increase the batch size eventually once i get a success code, and loop is the option as there are chances of timeout, so want to start the batch right where it stop

Comment: If I have your logic...you are loading a temp table with all the ID's you want to process, then running a script on a set number on records and deleting them from that table.  Since you are deleting as you process them, I don't see why it couldn't be 'restarted' just by running it again (without the table load) as the table should just have id's of records not yet processed.  Once again, you are introducing a large number of reads and writes (and deletes) to this entire process and will probably see a 100x run time increase, I'd recommend rethinking this as a solution.

Comment: Hi Twelfth , you exactly got requirement , it's just trial basis i am trying to implement this , what would be the best solution according to you , as it's hung amont of select insert and delete that is going to take place

Comment: Did you (user2116389) figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Here is my sample.

What happened to me is that my dba "team" .. screwed up setting Replication for us.
So .. over the weekend, working like dogs.... we had to write some code to "pull over" records from a source database to a destination database, where the structure of the database was the same.  We had to fake-out some replication.

We had 8,000,000 rows, and we would pull them over 10,000 at a time.
Below, I have about 1000 rows, and set the "number of rows to pull at one time" to 333.
I also put a @MaximumLoopCounter as a "just in case".  I didn't want to accidentally create a endless loop.

The sample below bases its "while" logic on "while exists (some records on the source-database-table that are not in the destination-database-table)"...keep grabbing those records.

I'm trying to help you answer your question.  In our case, we finally got replication working correctly, and we were able to abandon these scripts.  It was NOT a fun weekend.

/* SETUP */

```
if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable]
    END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] (
    CodeCategoryUUID [uniqueidentifier] not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() , 
    CodeCategoryName varchar(64) not null
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CodeCategorySourceTable_CodeCategoryUUID
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CodeCategoryUUID)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CodeCategorySourceTable_CodeCategoryName_UNIQUE 
UNIQUE (CodeCategoryName)
GO



if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]
    END
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] (
    CodeCategoryUUID [uniqueidentifier] not null default NEWSEQUENTIALID() , 
    CodeCategoryName varchar(64) not null
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CodeCategoryDestinationTable_CodeCategoryUUID
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CodeCategoryUUID)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CodeCategoryDestinationTable_CodeCategoryName_UNIQUE 
UNIQUE (CodeCategoryName)
GO




declare @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID01 uniqueidentifier
declare @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID03 uniqueidentifier
declare @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID02 uniqueidentifier
declare @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName01 varchar(64)
declare @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName02 varchar(64)
declare @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName03 varchar(64)
declare @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName01 varchar(64)
declare @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName02 varchar(64)
declare @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName03 varchar(64)



select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID01 = NEWID(), @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID02 = NEWID(), @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID03 = NEWID()
select @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName01 = 'NewOne', @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName02 = 'NewTwo', @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName03 = 'NewThree'
select @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName01 = 'OldOne', @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName02 = 'OldTwo', @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName03 = 'OldThree'


Insert Into [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] ( CodeCategoryUUID , CodeCategoryName )
Select top 1000 NEWID() , convert(varchar(40), NEWID()) + 'Name' from dbo.sysobjects so1 cross join dbo.sysobjects so2


Insert Into [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] ( CodeCategoryUUID , CodeCategoryName )
select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID01, @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName01 
UNION ALL select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID02, @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName02
UNION ALL select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID03, @AlreadyExistingNewCodeCategoryName03


select count(*) from [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] as CodeCategorySourceTableCOUNT



Insert Into  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] ( CodeCategoryUUID , CodeCategoryName )
select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID01, @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName01
UNION ALL select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID02, @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName02
UNION ALL select @AlreadyExistingCodeCategoryUUID03, @AlreadyExistingOldCodeCategoryName03

select count(*) from  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] as CodeCategoryDestinationTableCOUNT
```

/* USP */

```
print '[uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer]'
go


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer]
Go


/*


declare @numberRowsAffected  int
declare @ErrorNumber int

exec [dbo].[uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer] @numberRowsAffected output , @ErrorNumber  output

print @numberRowsAffected 
print @ErrorNumber 
print ''

*/



CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer] (
@numberRowsAffected int output
,
@ErrorNumber int output
)

AS


SET NOCOUNT ON

select @ErrorNumber = 0

declare @ErrorTracker int 
declare @insertRowCount int
declare @updateRowCount int 
select @insertRowCount = 0
select @updateRowCount = 0
declare @CurrentInsertCount int



declare @ManualReplicationRowCount int
select @ManualReplicationRowCount = 333


declare @MaximumLoopCounter int 
select @MaximumLoopCounter = 10000



while (@MaximumLoopCounter > 0) and exists 
(
    Select
        TOP 1 null
        from [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] sourceTable with (nolock)
        where not exists
        (
            select null from  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] destinationTable with (nolock) 
            Where
                destinationTable.CodeCategoryUUID = sourceTable.CodeCategoryUUID 
        )
)



    BEGIN


        select @MaximumLoopCounter = @MaximumLoopCounter - 1

        /*  DELETE FROM  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] */

        SET NOCOUNT OFF

        Insert into  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]  
        (   
                CodeCategoryUUID, 
                CodeCategoryName

        )

        Select

            TOP (@ManualReplicationRowCount)

                CodeCategoryUUID, 
                CodeCategoryName

            from [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] sourceTable with (nolock)

            where not exists
            (
                select null from  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]   destinationTable with (nolock) 
                Where
                    destinationTable.CodeCategoryUUID = sourceTable.CodeCategoryUUID 
            )




            SELECT @CurrentInsertCount = @@ROWCOUNT , @ErrorTracker = @@ERROR
            select @insertRowCount = @insertRowCount + @CurrentInsertCount

            if @ErrorTracker <> 0
                BEGIN

                    select @ErrorNumber = @ErrorTracker 
                    select @MaximumLoopCounter = 0 /*Bail Out !!!*/
                END



            SET NOCOUNT ON




    END /*End While Loop*/











print '/Before Look  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] */'
select * from  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]



SET NOCOUNT OFF

/* A little extra.  Update any non-surrogate-key values... We did not do this, but I leave it here as for kicks */

Update  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]
Set
  /*CodeCategoryUUID = vart.CodeCategoryUUID,*/
CodeCategoryName = sourceTable.CodeCategoryName
From
     [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] destinationTable, [dbo].[CodeCategorySourceTable] sourceTable
Where
/*Relationship*/
destinationTable.CodeCategoryUUID = sourceTable.CodeCategoryUUID  
/*Filter*/
and destinationTable.CodeCategoryName <> sourceTable.CodeCategoryName


SELECT @updateRowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

SET NOCOUNT ON

print '/After Look  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] */'
select * from  [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable]




print '/@insertRowCount COUNT/'
print @insertRowCount 
print '-------------------------'

print '/@updateRowCount COUNT/'
print @updateRowCount 
print '-------------------------'

SELECT @numberRowsAffected = @insertRowCount + @updateRowCount


print '/ [dbo].[CodeCategoryDestinationTable] COUNT/'
print @numberRowsAffected 
print '-------------------------'







SET NOCOUNT OFF


GO

/*GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.uspCodeCategoryReplicateReplacer TO $(DBUSERNAME)*/

GO
```

/* Improvement , encapsulate the ManualReplicationRowCount "getter" so it can be changed in one place  */

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[uspInternalSettingGetManualReplicationRowCount]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInternalSettingGetManualReplicationRowCount]
GO

/*

--START TEST

declare @returnCode int
declare @ManualReplicationRowCount int

EXEC @returnCode = dbo.uspInternalSettingGetManualReplicationRowCount @ManualReplicationRowCount output
print @ManualReplicationRowCount
print '/@returnCode/'
print @returnCode




*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspInternalSettingGetManualReplicationRowCount] (
@ManualReplicationRowCount int output  --return
)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON 

select @ManualReplicationRowCount = 333

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
```

Comment: THanks , granadacoder , your logic seems to be very helpfull for me , will come up with questions if i have any problem implementing it , thanks once again : )

Comment: might be a dumb question.. but why not load your replica db with the use of BCP?

Comment: I wish we had time to think about different options.  My manager (on Thursday night at 10 PM) was like "We need to have this done by Monday morning".  The dba's (who promised reliable replication) were no where to be found.  AND it wasn't a one time operation, every night we had to bring over the data.  We did the best we could under the grueling circumstances.  Basically, we worked every hour we could Thurs night until Mon morning.....I think it was at the end of that Thursday night (4AM...staying up all night) that I was like "I gotta get out of here".  DBA's never took one ounce of blame.

Comment: And I had to do this for 95 tables.  So I created a small program that was "code that created code".  So I was able to get the skeleton code done quickly, with some tweaks.  Bottom line : I was in survival mode.

Comment: :) well i guess that's what DBAs are famous for , dumping all on us but truely appreciate your hard work on it and i understand that pressure as i am new-intermidiate to SQL so everyday it's a challange for me ,and i love my work so far

Comment: We didn't "dump" on the dba's. They had like over 2 months to work with and figure out replication correctly.  After we got through the storm, me and another co-worker went down to see how replication was being setup.  Basically, "right click" "add publisher" and "right click" "add subscriber".  But there are like 100+ options for setting up replication that cannot be done from memory.  Once, they forget to check the "Keep Foreign Keys" button, so the subscriber lost all referential integrity.  Basically, they had no interest in creating tsql scripts to setup replication for repeatability.  :<

Comment: Well that is it , no tsql . they wanted a simple click n go method